# Показывать блок при наведении на элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно чтобы в начале отображался первый блок с text1. Как будто уже навели на item1. Уже после как навели на другой item показывать соответствующий им блок.

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu__item {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #60a3bc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.menu__item:hover .content {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 34%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">
      Item1
      <div class="content">
        text1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      Item2
      <div class="content">
        text2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      Item3
      <div class="content">
        text3
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вам помог этот ответ, тогда примите его, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

А если просто его показывать по-умолчанию? Или я не правильно понял проблему?

```css
.menu {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu__item {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #60a3bc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.menu__item:hover .content {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 34%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50%;
}
.defs {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">
      Item1
      <div class="content defs">
        text1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      Item2
      <div class="content">
        text2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menu__item">
      Item3
      <div class="content">
        text3
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично. Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы сохранялось состояние? например навели на item2 и остался text2, даже если убрали курсор от этих блоков